# Which slokas in 4 vedas tell us about vedic astrology

Tags: vedas, astrology

Please give reference form vedas only.

Comment: You are very unlikely to find references in mantras (samhita portion). If you want some other references please tell @ram in the previous question itself, he’ll give you. There’s no point making duplicates.

Comment: Although it's not veda. Read Brihat parashara https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%201%20RSanthanam/mode/2up

Comment: Vedas don't talk about Vedic astrology. If you continue restricting all your questions like this then chances are the questions will go unanswered.